# How to create a new table with a modified schema from another?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am working with Google BigQuery on GCP.

I want to copy the schema of an existing table and change 1 of the fields(`foobar`) that is now of `STRING` type to  `RECORD` and create `foobar.potato`, `foobar.nada`, ..., `foobar.apple` and create a new table with the new schema.

What's the best/fastest way to do it? Unfortunately there's many fields so I can't just create a new table manually.

Found a way to collect the schema via:

```
SELECT
 * EXCEPT(is_generated, generation_expression, is_stored, is_updatable)
FROM
 `myproject`.mydataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE
 table_name="old_table"
```

Didn't help me much. And when I try to edit the schema of a table in hopes to grab that "text-schema" it is only for the new fields.

Comment: How are you converting the string to a struct?

Comment: I was aiming to do it manually just for the schema of the new table. I don't care much for the old data, since the new data that I will upload already treat is as a struct and not as a string. Gonna test your answer and will let you know. Thanks!

Comment: Not familiar with BigQuery so forgive me if this doesn’t apply, but many database apps have a “get create schema” function. Essentially it returns the syntax for creating a table. There are parameters also to do this in a backup file. Then just open the file and copy the language you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just wanted to create a new table, it would look something like this:

```
select t.* except (foobar),
       struct('potato' as potato, 'nada' as nada) as foobar
from t;
```

If you only want the structure, you can do something like:

```
create table `newtable` as
    select t.* except (foobar),
           struct('potato' as potato, 'nada' as nada) as foobar
    from t
    where false;
```

Comment: Thanks, the second one was what I wanted!

Comment: I don't know if I should make a new question or edit but if I want `foobar` to be `REPEATED` instead of the `NULLABLE` mode, what do I need to add?

Comment: @Lev . . . You would create the value as an `ARRAY`.